# Exercise of expressions for ideal op-amp based amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

> (i) Obtain an expression for the CMRR of a difference amplifier, in terms of the tolerance of the resistances used in the amplifier. Hint: Assume that 1/2=(3/4)(1+), where  is the degree of mismatch. Relate  to the tolerance of the resistances ().
> (ii) Plot the relationship between CMRR and .
> (iii) From the plot obtained in (ii) above, determine the tolerance required for a CMRR of 100 dB.

I know how to calculate gain via resistance but I don't know how to correlate resistance with tolerance of resistors and degree of mismatch. Can you please help with that. (We can take tolerance of each resistor as 1%.) I have added my work on finding gain.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your title is designing an operational amplifier <-- do you really mean that or, do you actually mean designing a circuit that uses an operational amplifier?

Comment: I am designing an operational amplifier a difference amplifier to be precise. I am not designing any circuit that uses it

Comment: Operational amplifiers are made up of transistors, if you are talking about gains and external components then you are designing the opamps circuit

Comment: Ok! I didnt know that before. I am designing an opamp circuit. Thanks for the clarification. Can u please help me with the question

Comment: *(We can take tolerance of each resistor as 1%.)* According to the problem the tolerance is a variable, so you can't just assume the resistors are 1%.  And 1% won't get you anywhere near 100 dB CMRR.  I remember working this problem many years ago, it's not that difficult, just keep at it.

Comment: I would say that 100 dB CMRR would need 0.001 % of tolerance for the resistors ...

Comment: This is a standard exercise which is to be found in classical electronics engineering textbooks: I remember that I saw in it Gasparini and Mirri *Principi di elettronica* (in Italian) which, however takes most of its contents from the work of Giacoletto, Huelsman, Graeme, Tobey, Millman, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach (starting with your last handwritten equation):

1. **Differential gain**: For the nominal case \$R_2/R_1=R_4/R_3\$ we get
   $$
   V_\text{o,d}=\frac{R_2}{R_1}({V_2-V_1}) 
   $$
   and thus
   $$
   A_d=\frac{V_\text{o,d}}{V_2-V_1}=\frac{R_2}{R1}
   $$
2. **Common mode gain**: For \$V_1=V_2=V_\text{cm}\$ we can write
   $$
   V_\text{o,cm}=V_\text{cm}\left[\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4}\cdot\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1} - \frac{R_2}{R_1}\right]
   $$
   and thus
   $$
   A_\text{cm}=\frac{V_\text{o,cm}}{V_\text{cm}}=\frac{R_1R_4-R_2R_3}{R_1(R_3+R_4)}
   $$
3. **Common Mode Rejection:**
   $$
   \text{CMRR}=\frac{A_d}{A_\text{cm}}=\frac{R_2R_3+R_2R_4}{R_1R_4-R_2R_3}
   $$
   (which will go to infinity for \$R_1R_4=R_2R_3\$).
   This expression can also be written as
   $$
   \text{CMRR}=\frac{1+\dfrac{R_4}{R_3}}{\dfrac{R_1R_4}{R_2R_3} - 1}
   $$
4. To **see the influence of mismatch** you can now introduce the given expression
   $$
   \frac{R_1}{R_2}=\frac{R_3}{R_4}(1+\alpha).
   $$

Comment: @Daniel T. - thanks for editing (and improving the readability)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Maple sheet to show how "errors" are assumed ...

[image]

[image]

Here is a simulation with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110), where R2 is varying only 0.5 Ohm ...
The curve in "black" is Gdiff, the curve in "red" is CMRR for R10=-0.5 Ohm -> -130 dB.

[image]